# Data is not being written in Excel file and no error is thrown in Robot framework

Tags: robotframework, openpyxl

I am trying to write a value returned from application to an existing excel  file in Robot framework

I have a .py file having the below code

```
def writeData(file,sheetname,rownum, colnum,data):
workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(file)
sheet = workbook[sheetname]
sheet.cell(row=rownum, column=colnum).value= data
workbook.save(file)
```

And i am calling this in my common.robot file

```
WriteToExcel
  ${excel}  set variable     writedata       ${fileName}     Sheet1    10      10       ${refNumber}
```

After execution , I dont see any error nor there is any value written in excel file.

Comment: That's because "Set Variable" is for assigning value(s) to a variable - and now `${excel}` is a list of strings.

Comment: I am fairly new to robot framework. not very sure of the details yet.
I editing it to
 @{excel}   create list    excelreadwrite.writedata       ${fileName}     Sheet1    10      10       ${OrderNumber}

still I am facing the same issue. Could you please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Robot Framework is designed for the user to call keywords in the cases' body.

When you call `${x}=    Set Variable   value`, you're telling it "call the keyword Set Variable, and assign the result to variable x". `Set Variable` is used for what its name says - static assignment of value(s) to an identifier (a variable's name). You've said in the comments you tried to change it to `Create List` *(perhaps my comment mislead you to that, sorry!)*, which will do again what its name says - it'll create a list (all the arguments you pass to it will become the members), and will assign it to the variable.

Now, you have created a keyword - `writeData`, that does something you want it to do. How shall you make it execute? Just, call it; no `Set Variable`, or other keywords needed.
If "WriteToExcel" is the name of the case, then:

```
WriteToExcel
    writedata       ${fileName}     Sheet1    10      10
```

, should do it.

I've deliberately left out the `${excel}` variable prefixing the call in your question - because looking at the python's method definition, it does not have a `return` statement - it doesn't return anything, so nothing to assign.
If you ever change that function to now return some value, the way to call it in RF would be:

```
WriteToExcel
    ${excel}=    writedata_that_returns_something       ${fileName}     Sheet1    10      10
```

Comment: When i just called the keyword, it was giving me TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int' robot framework
now I slightly  modified and called row and column together like instead of 
  ws.cell(row=rownum, column=colnum).value = value , used ws[rownum]=value  and it is working. thank you for you help